# making a request to find members of a group in GCP

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-groups-api

this is the request I need to make (trying to get list of members in a google group):

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/list?apix_params=%7B%22groupKey%22%3A%22devops%40flight-analytics.com%22%2C%22includeDerivedMembership%22%3Atrue%2C%22maxResults%22%3A200%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%7D
```

group key in this case is email for the group eg: xyx@myorg.com
how can i make it into a python script and get my results.

this is the attempt I was expecting to work.

```
def make_request(request):
    """
    HTTP Cloud Function that makes another HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """
    import requests

    # The URL to send the request to
    #url = 'https://google.com'
    
    # Process the request
    response = requests.get(request)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response)
    print(response.text)
    print(response.raise_for_status())
    print("Success")
    return 'Success!'

make_request("https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/xyx@myorg.com/members")
```

But the script fails saying i dont have proper login but i did ran:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth application-default login
```

before firing the python script in same shell but end up getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deepak.sandhu/Desktop/test.py", line 55, in <module>
    make_request("https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/xyz@myorg.com/members")
  File "/Users/deepak.sandhu/Desktop/test.py", line 48, in make_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/xyz@myorg.com/members
```

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud auth login` authorizes the CLI (gcloud). Use `gcloud auth application-default login` to authorize application credentials.

[gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

Comment: tried with this also (gcloud auth application-default login) but still same response.

Comment: @Deepak - Which credential type are you authenticating with? If you are using a service account, you must implement impersonation (Domain Wide Delegation of Authority). https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation If you are using user credentials, then the user is missing the required OAuth Scope. Add more details to your question.

Comment: i am using user credentials of my iam account and have owner in organization.

Comment: @Deepak - Google Cloud and Google Workspace are different services. You are interacting with Workspace. You need permission for that service. https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9886284?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the members in the group, you need to have atleast the group viewer role. The role is managed from admin console(admin.google.com). Role can be granted by org administrator or group administrator.

I recently did it for my terraform code to view the members in the group and it seems to be working fine.